# How to crash R?

Tags: r, crash

Is there a simple way to trigger a crash in R?  This is for testing purposes only, to see how a certain program that uses R in the background reacts to a crash and help determine if some rare problems are due to crashes or not.

Comment: I've tried `options(expressions=300000)` then running an infinite recursion but R is written well enough that it doesn't crash :)

Comment: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?query_format=specific&order=relevance+desc&no_redirect=0&bug_status=__open__&product=&content=crash

Comment: This may depend on your platform. Want to add that info?

Comment: @StephanKolassa I'm on OS X, but I'd rather keep the question general for the sake of future readers.  Answers specific to any platform are acceptable.

Comment: Can downvoters explain what they consider to be wrong with the question?  @DirkEddelbuettel  Please be tolerant, that does not make the solution obvious to everyone.  A link to the man page doesn't make it clear how to do this.

Comment: Must it be a crash? Could you simply `quit` with a non-zero status instead?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The easiest way is to call `C`-code. `C` provides a standard function `abort()`[<sup>[1]</sup>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abort/) that does what you want. You need to call: `.Call("abort")`.

As @Phillip pointed out you may need to load `libc` via:

- on Linux, `dyn.load("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6")` before issuing `.Call("abort")`. The path may of course vary depending on your system.
- on OS X, `dyn.load("/usr/lib/libc.dylib")`
- on Windows (I just tested it on XP as I could not get hold of a newer version.) you will need to install `Rtools`[<sup>[2]</sup>](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/). After that you should load `dyn.load("C:/.../Rtools/bin/cygwin1.dll")`.

Comment: When running R from the command line or using the official GUI, I get `Error in .Call("abort") : C symbol name "abort" not in load table`.  When using RStudio it crashes.

Comment: Strange, I use it from the command line and I get: `Abort (core dumped)`.

Comment: You've got to load libc before: `dyn.load("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6")`. The path may vary on your system, use `locate libc.so.6` to find it.

Comment: @Phillip Thanks!  On OS X that would be `/usr/lib/libc.dylib`.  lord.garbage, can you update your answer with the info provided by Phillip?

Comment: That is cheating as `abort()` and `assert()` and ... are all declared inadmissible by the [CRAN Policy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html).

Comment: The `crash` package calls `abort` as well. At least as far as I can see but I'm not nearly as experienced as you are!

Comment: So it'll never get on CRAN :)

Comment: Hello @Joshua, I am currently not on a Windows machine. The last time I successfully called `C` functions on a Windows machine from `R` it involved installing either a complete `Cygwin` environment or the `Rtools` package. If there is an easier way I am unfortunately not aware of it.

Comment: You probably meant the Rtools package as R was never supported on Cygwin. What Joshua was too polite to mention directly is that your answer isn't fully portable this way.  But yes, `abort()` is the key.

Answer (score 49):

There is an entire [package on GitHub](https://github.com/jdanielnd/crash) dedicated to this:

> crash
>
> R package that purposely crash an R session. WARNING: intended
>   for test.

How to [install a package from github](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+install+from+github) is covered in other questions.

Comment: And it calls `abort`, nice.

Comment: Assuming you have the required tools installed ([*nix](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Essential-and-useful-other-programs-under-a-Unix_002dalike), [Windows](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset)), one way to install this package from github is: `library(devtools); install_github('jdanielnd/crash')`. Then you can crash your R session with `library(crash); crash()`

Answer (score 17):

I'm going to steal an idea from @Spacedman, but I'm giving him full conceptual credit by copying from his Twitter feed:

> Segfault #rstats in one easy step:
>   `options(device=function(){});plot(1)`
>   reported Danger, will crash your R session.
>   — Barry Rowlingson (@geospacedman) [July 16, 2014](https://twitter.com/geospacedman/statuses/489344772780617728)

Comment: This is useful because it doesn't exit right away, instead it presents a prompt and asks what to do next.  It's a different sort of behaviour which may also be what's going wrong in my own project ...

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned in a comment to your question, the minimal approach is a simple call to the system function `abort()`.  One way to do this in one line is to

```
R> Rcpp::cppFunction('int crashMe(int ignored) { ::abort(); }'); 
R> crashMe(123)
Aborted (core dumped)
$
```

or you can use the inline package:

```
R> library(inline)
R> crashMe <- cfunction(body="::abort();")
R> crashMe()
Aborted (core dumped)
$
```

You can of course also do this outside of Rcpp or inline, but then you need to deal with the system-dependent ways of compiling, linking and loading.

Comment: The above snippet crashes to desktop (in a low-mem env) after the first line. Here be dragons.

Comment: @DeerHunter.  I also noticed that on maybe one out five attempts.  There must be a race somewhere.  Then again, R isn't exactly designed to be `abort()`ed.

Answer (score 6):

I'll do this in plain C because my C++-foo isn't Dirkian:

Create a C file, `segv.c`:

```
#include <signal.h>
void crashme(){raise(SIGSEGV);}
```

Compile it at the command line (windows users will have to work this out for themselves):

```
R CMD SHLIB segv.c
```

In R, load and run:

```
dyn.load("segv.so") # or possibly .dll for Windows users
.C("crashme")
```

Producing a segfault:

```
> .C("crashme")

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x1d9e, cause 'unknown'

Traceback:
 1: .C("crashme")

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection: 1
aborting ...
Segmentation fault
```

This is the same behaviour as the one Thomas references in the graphics system bug report which I have filed and might get fixed one day. However this two-liner will always raise a segfault...

Maybe Dirk can one-line-Rcpp-ise it?

Comment: Re-read my post, the inline use is entirely C -- I use `cfunction()` i in C mode.  You could do the same here to make your answer easier/more concise/less OS-dependent.  The Rcpp use is 'merely' to deploy the even easier build mechanism, there is no C++ there per se.

Comment: `spacedman <- inline::cfunction(body="raise(SIGSEGV);", include="#include <signal.h>")`  -- and no C++ was harmed^Hused in this answer.

Comment: `spacedman <- Rcpp::cppFunction("void crashme() { ::raise(SIGSEGV); }", includes="#include <signal.h>")` -- so there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to crash your R, try this

```
lapply("", function(x) eval(sys.call(1)))
```

(Save everything before running because this immediately results in "R Session Aborted")

Edit: This works for me on Windows 10.

Comment: At least on macOS there seems to be some protection in place against stack overflow. This results in "Error: C stack usage  7971744 is too close to the limit", but no crash.